Continuity of $L_p$ norms
I am solving Exercise 3.21 of section 4 in Erhan Cinlar's book - Probability and Stochastics. The question is:

Fix a random variable $X$. Define $f(p)=\|X\|_p$ for $p\in[1,\infty]$. Show that the function $f$ is continuous except possibly at one point $p_0$, where $p_0$ is such that
$$
f(p)<\infty \text{ for } p<p_0, f(p)=\infty \text{ for } p>p_0, 
$$
and $f$ is left-continuous at $p_0$.

I have showed that $f$ is continuous at $p=\infty$ for $f(\infty)<\infty$ and $f(\infty)=\infty$. I am trying to show continuity of $f$ for $p\in[1,\infty)$. I think that the argument is supposed to follow something like this: If $(p_n)\to p$,
$$
\lim_n f(p_n) = \lim_n e^{\log (\mathbb{E}[|X|^{p_n}]^{1/p_n})} = \lim_n e^{\frac
{1}{p_n}\log\mathbb{E}[|X|^{p_n}]} = e^{\lim_n \frac{1}{p_n}\log\mathbb{E}[|X|^{p_n}]}.
$$
By the Dominated Convergence Theorem, $\lim_n \mathbb{E}[|X|^{p_n}]=\mathbb{E}[|X|^p]$, but I am not sure what the dominating random variable is here. I am also not sure how to handle the $p_0$ case mentioned in the question. I tried working with an example like $X(\omega)=\omega^{-1/2}$ for $\omega\in[0,1]$ and here $p_0=2$, but I don't see why right continuity fails if we're working in the extended real line.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For any $p' > p$ for which $E(|X|^{p'}) < \infty$, $(1 \lor |X|)^{p'}$ works as a dominating variable

What happens at $p$ for which $\mathbb{E}[|X|^p]=\infty$?

By Jensen's inequality, you know that $f$ is increasing, so there is $p_0$ for which $f(p) < \infty$ for $p < p_0$ and $f(p) = \infty$ for $p > p_0$. The DCT argument works to show that $f$ is continuous at $p$ when $p < p_0$. The only case that remains is continuity at $p = p_0$.
